# Firefox proxy settings keep on changing when start from remotely

Tags: firefox, proxy, settings

In Firefox I have set the proxy settings to 'No proxy'. But when I start it remotely (through Jenkins) it always set to 'Use system proxy settings' and not loading the expected page. It gives 'proxy server is refusing connections'. This happened when I tried to execute selenium webdriver scripts through Jenkins from a remote machine. I haven't defined any firefox profiles in selenium script even.

Answer (score 1):

After spending a day on this issue I found that just proxy setting might not work.
It is required update the default proxy type manually in below location.

Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\defaults\pref` and add an entry to `channel-prefs.js` as below:

```js
pref("network.proxy.type", 0);
    
/*
0 = No proxy;
1 = Manual proxy configuration;
2 = Proxy auto-configuration (PAC);
4 = Auto-detect proxy settings.
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I put this into my `mozilla.cfg` file and it solved the problem.

```
pref("network.proxy.type", 4);
```

Answer (score -2):

My computer wouldn't let me change the defaults, so I deleted the file and restarted Firefox.  End of problem!

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer. Please refrain from posting commentary as an answer.